# Clear icon 'x' missing when using ng-template for ng-select

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ng-template

When using ng-template for the selected items. the 'x' icon to remove the element is missing, the package's documentation about using ng-template is kinda poor so I've been digging through their source with no luck.

I've put together this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-select-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) so you can reproduce the issue

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <ng-select 
  [items]="availableItems" 
  [multiple]="true" 
  [closeOnSelect]="false"
    [hideSelected]="true" 
  [searchable]="true" 
  placeholder="Choose an item" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
     name="item">
        <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-select>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  availableItems = [
    { id: 1, name: 'name 1', value: 'value 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'name2', value: 'value 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'name 3', value: 'value 3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'name 4', value: 'value 4' }
  ];
  selectedItems = [
    { id: 2, name: 'name2', value: 'value 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'name 3', value: 'value 3' },
  ]
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: In chrome, Edge. It works. However, there are some CSS issues in IE. I believe it is a cross-browser compatibility issue. Check your browser

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When passing in a custom template, you need to define the clear button inside of it. Please refer to the documentation here: https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect

What you need to have is a template similar to the following:

```
<ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item" let-clear="clear">
    <span class="ng-value-label">{{item.login}}</span>
    <span class="ng-value-icon right" (click)="clear(item)">×</span>
</ng-template>
```

I've modified your StackBlitz to add this functionality. You can find it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-select-issue-kptlkt).

Comment: Thanks. It works. But what exactly "let-clear" does?

Comment: @rostamiani It reuses components clear method. So you don't need to reimplemet clear logic.